# Setting a transparent main window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How to set main window background transparent on QT? Do I need an attribute or a style?
I've tried setting the opacity, but it didn't work for me.

```
app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {opacity:0}")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you must set new attribute for MainWindow object as below:

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `windowOpacity` property:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop

Comment: main window opacity = 0; all content,child window = 0 :) (dosen't show and visible)

Comment: This will make the entire window non-opaque, not just the background.