# Semi-transparent background in a PyQt5 window (IT IS NOT A DUPLICATE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, alpha-transparency

I need to put a semi-transparent background to a PyQt5 window (by semi-transparent I mean it is possible to see what is behind it.).

What I saw in many other subjects is that the idea is to use a rgba color. For example putting something like this `self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 120);')`, where 120 correspond to alpha.

But I tried this and it is not working (see example below) and I don't understand why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

ps : I also tried to test setStyleSheet("background:transparent;") and this is also not working...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
The MIT License (MIT)
Copyright (c) 2017 fbjorn
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
"""

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



from pyqtspinner.spinner import WaitingSpinner


class Demo(QWidget):
    sb_roundness = None
    sb_opacity = None
    sb_fadeperc = None
    sb_lines = None
    sb_line_length = None
    sb_line_width = None
    sb_inner_radius = None
    sb_rev_s = None

    btn_start = None
    btn_stop = None
    btn_pick_color = None

    spinner = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        groupbox1 = QGroupBox()
        groupbox1_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        groupbox2 = QGroupBox()
        groupbox2_layout = QGridLayout()
        button_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setWindowTitle("QtWaitingSpinner Demo")
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 120);')
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Dialog)

        # SPINNER
        self.spinner = WaitingSpinner(self)

        # Spinboxes
        self.sb_roundness = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.sb_opacity = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.sb_fadeperc = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.sb_lines = QSpinBox()
        self.sb_line_length = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.sb_line_width = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.sb_inner_radius = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.sb_rev_s = QDoubleSpinBox()

        # set spinbox default values
        self.sb_roundness.setValue(70)
        self.sb_roundness.setRange(0, 9999)
        self.sb_opacity.setValue(15)
        self.sb_opacity.setRange(0, 9999)
        self.sb_fadeperc.setValue(70)
        self.sb_fadeperc.setRange(0, 9999)
        self.sb_lines.setValue(12)
        self.sb_lines.setRange(1, 9999)
        self.sb_line_length.setValue(10)
        self.sb_line_length.setRange(0, 9999)
        self.sb_line_width.setValue(5)
        self.sb_line_width.setRange(0, 9999)
        self.sb_inner_radius.setValue(10)
        self.sb_inner_radius.setRange(0, 9999)
        self.sb_rev_s.setValue(1)
        self.sb_rev_s.setRange(0.1, 9999)

        # Buttons
        self.btn_start = QPushButton("Start")
        self.btn_stop = QPushButton("Stop")
        self.btn_pick_color = QPushButton("Pick Color")
        self.btn_show_init = QPushButton("Show init args")

        # Connects
        self.sb_roundness.valueChanged.connect(self.set_roundness)
        self.sb_opacity.valueChanged.connect(self.set_opacity)
        self.sb_fadeperc.valueChanged.connect(self.set_fadeperc)
        self.sb_lines.valueChanged.connect(self.set_lines)
        self.sb_line_length.valueChanged.connect(self.set_line_length)
        self.sb_line_width.valueChanged.connect(self.set_line_width)
        self.sb_inner_radius.valueChanged.connect(self.set_inner_radius)
        self.sb_rev_s.valueChanged.connect(self.set_rev_s)

        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.spinner_start)
        self.btn_stop.clicked.connect(self.spinner_stop)
        self.btn_pick_color.clicked.connect(self.show_color_picker)
        self.btn_show_init.clicked.connect(self.show_init_args)

        # Layout adds
        groupbox1_layout.addWidget(self.spinner)
        groupbox1.setLayout(groupbox1_layout)

        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Roundness:"), *(1, 1))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(self.sb_roundness, *(1, 2))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Opacity:"), *(2, 1))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(self.sb_opacity, *(2, 2))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Fade Perc:"), *(3, 1))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(self.sb_fadeperc, *(3, 2))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Lines:"), *(4, 1))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(self.sb_lines, *(4, 2))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Line Length:"), *(5, 1))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(self.sb_line_length, *(5, 2))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Line Width:"), *(6, 1))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(self.sb_line_width, *(6, 2))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Inner Radius:"), *(7, 1))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(self.sb_inner_radius, *(7, 2))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Rev/s:"), *(8, 1))
        groupbox2_layout.addWidget(self.sb_rev_s, *(8, 2))

        groupbox2.setLayout(groupbox2_layout)

        button_hbox.addWidget(self.btn_start)
        button_hbox.addWidget(self.btn_stop)
        button_hbox.addWidget(self.btn_pick_color)
        button_hbox.addWidget(self.btn_show_init)

        grid.addWidget(groupbox1, *(1, 1))
        grid.addWidget(groupbox2, *(1, 2))
        grid.addLayout(button_hbox, *(2, 1))

        self.spinner.start()
        self.show()

    def set_roundness(self):
        self.spinner.setRoundness(self.sb_roundness.value())

    def set_opacity(self):
        self.spinner.setMinimumTrailOpacity(self.sb_opacity.value())

    def set_fadeperc(self):
        self.spinner.setTrailFadePercentage(self.sb_fadeperc.value())

    def set_lines(self):
        self.spinner.setNumberOfLines(self.sb_lines.value())

    def set_line_length(self):
        self.spinner.setLineLength(self.sb_line_length.value())

    def set_line_width(self):
        self.spinner.setLineWidth(self.sb_line_width.value())

    def set_inner_radius(self):
        self.spinner.setInnerRadius(self.sb_inner_radius.value())

    def set_rev_s(self):
        self.spinner.setRevolutionsPerSecond(self.sb_rev_s.value())

    def spinner_start(self):
        self.spinner.start()

    def spinner_stop(self):
        self.spinner.stop()

    def show_color_picker(self):
        self.spinner.setColor(QColorDialog.getColor())

    def show_init_args(self):
        text = (
            'WaitingSpinner(\n'
            '    parent,\n'
            '    roundness={}, opacity={},\n'
            '    fade={}, radius={}, lines={},\n'
            '    line_length={}, line_width={},\n'
            '    speed={}, color={}\n'
            ')\n'
        ).format(
            self.sb_roundness.value(), self.sb_opacity.value(),
            self.sb_fadeperc.value(), self.sb_inner_radius.value(),
            self.sb_lines.value(), self.sb_line_length.value(),
            self.sb_line_width.value(), self.sb_rev_s.value(),
            self.spinner.color.getRgb()[:3]
        )

        msg_box = QMessageBox(text=text)
        msg_box.setWindowTitle('Text was copied to clipboard')
        cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.clear(mode=cb.Clipboard)
        cb.setText(text, mode=cb.Clipboard)
        print(text)
        msg_box.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Demo()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

ps: I am sorry but I am afraid no solution is provided it the "duplicates" that are mentionned and the comments... Please reopen the subject.
Hello ?

Comment: use `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`

Comment: The answers are not only code but also have an explanation, and based on that explanation the solution can be implemented in any language. Also I have pointed out other duplicates written in python so please read it, and if you have any issues then use the comments instead of the edits

Comment: Sorry I have still a problem with this... The problem is that the backgroud (behind layouts) is totally transparent. How can I have a semi-transparent one ?

Comment: then use `self.setWindowOpacity(.9)` instead of `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`. Please read the answers

Comment: I already tried this setWindowOpacity() and the problem with this is that it is making ALL semi-transparent (buttons, text, spot bar...). What I need is just the background.

Comment: I am extremely sorry but i am afraid no solution is provided it the "duplicates" you mentionned...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013500/pyqt5-create-transparent-window-with-opaque-widgets

Comment: I don't understand if I put 
`window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)` the background is fully transparent and I cannot have a semi-transparent one.

Comment: Instead of putting IT IS NOT A DUPLICATE in the title, add details about how it's distinct from each proposed target / how the answers proposed (mis)behave when used to apply.

Comment: Also, please try to make sure your reproducer is a [mre]. "Minimal" is part of that, meaning it needs to be the **shortest possible code** that produces your problem when run without changes. And note that Stack Overflow's terms and conditions put content under [a specific license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), presently [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/); if you can't legally post content under that license, you can't post it here at all.

Comment: ...asking folks to dig through a whole demo app with a bunch of functionality not obviously related to transparency for a question that's _only_ about transparency is not a way to get a good response. Folks who aren't actually moderators can't change from a bad close reason to a good one -- voting to reopen something blocks someone from voting to close it with a different, more applicable reason -- so one reason for something to be left closed as a duplicate is folks who might otherwise be casting reopen votes thinking it _ought_ to be closed as not complying with the MRE rules.